# CD Key and License Key Organizer

Tags: software-rec

Is there an application or something that nicely will organize all my CD/Lics in a nice format other then using Excel?

Right now I keep them all in notepad and text files.

Comment: Google Docs seems like a good application for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LibreOffice, but it'll work the same way as Excel.  Since you're avoiding Excel, I'm assuming you just want a free spreadsheet option

Answer (score 0):

I use Google Docs for that, it's still a spreadsheet, but it's a piece of cake, accessible from all my devices, and easy to edit.